# how to show json data by date in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i have json data by dates i want to show schedule time for today.
how can this be implemented?
json file address https://volnaveri.by/tt.json

react native code

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, FlatList, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [],
      isLoading: true
    };
  }

  async getMovies() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('https://volnaveri.by/tt.json');
      const json = await response.json();
      this.setState({ data: json.times });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } finally {
      this.setState({ isLoading: false });
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getMovies();
  }

  render() {
    const { data, isLoading } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 24 }}>
        {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator/> : (
          <FlatList
            data={data}
            keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <Text>{item.Date}, {item.Monday}, {item.Tuesday}, {item.Monday}, {item.Wednesday}, {item.Thursday}</Text>
            )}
          />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
};
```

[so far this is what i got. photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WebrQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this.setState({ data: json.times });

To do:

> this.setState({ data: [data.times.find(time => time.Date.split('-')[2] === new Date().getDate()))]

Comment: in sign === syntax error

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected "," ( this.setState({ data: [data.times.find(time => time.Date.split('-')[2] === new Date().getDate()))]
     ^